# what is the function of formparam annotation?

Tags: java, annotations

I have the code below:

```
public class RequestBaseFormParamTO extends BaseFormParamTO {
    @FormParam("channelId")
    private String channelId;
    @FormParam("signatureString")
    private String signatureString;

    public String getChannelId() {
        return channelId;
    }

    public void setChannelId(String channelId) {
        this.channelId = channelId;
    }

    public String getSignatureString() {
        return signatureString;
    }

    public void setSignatureString(String signatureString) {
        this.signatureString = signatureString;
    }

}
```

what's the function of @FormParam annotation, what I know the @FormParam is used to get the value from html but in this case, the form param not place in the services. so, what's the function? I want to understand in this code. thanks

this is the other code class:

```
    public class BaseFormParamTO {
        @FormParam("transactionId")
        private String transactionId;
        @FormParam("transactionTime")
        private String transactionTime;

        public String getTransactionId() {
            return transactionId;
        }

        public void setTransactionId(String transactionId) {
            this.transactionId = transactionId;
        }

        public String getTransactionTime() {
            return transactionTime;
        }

        public void setTransactionTime(String transactionTime) {
            this.transactionTime = transactionTime;
        }
    }
```

Comment: can you share the fully quantified classname of that annotation?

Comment: okay. the other class I put below in my answer